# How to set ForkJoinPool's thread factory when using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, forkjoinpool

I want to set ForkJoinPool's thread factory by -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory=xxx in a spring boot application.

But it's not working,!!!

I found out that ForkJoinPool uses ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() to load the factory class yet ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() returns AppClassLoader, which cannot load the factory class

I think only org.springframework.loader.LaunchedURLCLassLoader can load the factory class, is that right??

what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you implement `ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory`？？

If your custom thread factory not implement `ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory`, it will raise a cast type error which will be ignored. Related code are copid from `ForkJoinPool.commonPool`  as follow:

```java
    private static ForkJoinPool makeCommonPool() {
        try {  // ignore exceptions in accessing/parsing properties
            //...
            String fp = System.getProperty
                ("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory");
            //...
            if (fp != null)
                factory = ((ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory)ClassLoader.
                           getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(fp).newInstance());
            //...
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
```